# Remove duplicates in Laravel collection only if previous item is identical

Tags: laravel-5, collections

I have a Laravel Collection of items:

```
[
    [
    'id' => 1,
    'path' => '/',
    'created_at' => '2020-05-20 20:12:00'
    ],
    [
    'id' => 2,
    'path' => '/somewhere',
    'created_at' => '2020-05-20 21:01:00'
    ],
    [
    'id' => 3,
    'path' => '/somewhere',
    'created_at' => '2020-05-20 21:21:00'
    ],
    [
    'id' => 4,
    'path' => '/somewhere/else',
    'created_at' => '2020-05-20 21:09:00'
    ],
    [
    'id' => 5,
    'path' => '/somewhere/else',
    'created_at' => '2020-05-20 21:10:00'
    ],
]
```

This is the raw data that would be found in the collection if I cast it to an array, but I need it to remain in collection format.

I need to remove any duplicates where the current item has the same `path` and is less than 5 minutes old compared to the previous item.

So in this case, item #4 would be removed leaving only #5, but items #2 and #3 would be kept even tho their paths are the same.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following namespace in your controller file:

```
use DateTime;
```

Use the following code in your controller file:

```
$collection = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'path' => '/',
            'created_at' => '2020-05-20 20:12:00'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'path' => '/somewhere',
            'created_at' => '2020-05-20 21:01:00'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 3,
            'path' => '/somewhere',
            'created_at' => '2020-05-20 21:21:00'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 4,
            'path' => '/somewhere/else',
            'created_at' => '2020-05-20 21:09:00'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 5,
            'path' => '/somewhere/else',
            'created_at' => '2020-05-20 21:10:00'
        ],
    ];

    $paths = [];
    $time_count = [];
    foreach ($collection as $key => $data) {

        if (in_array($data['path'], $paths)) {
            $arr_pos = array_search($data['path'], array_values($paths));

            $datetime1 = new DateTime($data['created_at']);
            $datetime2 = new DateTime($collection[$arr_pos]['created_at']);

            $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
            $mins = $interval->format('%i');
            if ($mins < 5) {
                unset($collection[$arr_pos]);
            }
        }
        $paths[] = $data['path'];
    }
```

This will return result:

```
array:4 [▼
     0 => array:3 [▼
       "id" => 1
       "path" => "/"
       "created_at" => "2020-05-20 20:12:00"
      ]
      1 => array:3 [▼
          "id" => 2
          "path" => "/somewhere"
         "created_at" => "2020-05-20 21:01:00"
      ]
      2 => array:3 [▼
         "id" => 3
         "path" => "/somewhere"
         "created_at" => "2020-05-20 21:21:00"
      ]    
      4 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 5
        "path" => "/somewhere/else"
        "created_at" => "2020-05-20 21:10:00"
      ]
     ]
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: What I gave was the data structure of a collection, not an array. I need to know how to do this while the data is still in Laravel Collection form.

Comment: You need to convert your collection into array ( $collection->toArray() ) and use the above code for best results.